# Error while running asp.net apps in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

In my company I'm running Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise and just recently upgraded to Windows 10. Unfortunately, now I can't run **any** web project using versions of asp.net earlier than 5 (owin/katana) - always getting error :

> "Could not load file1or assembly 'XXX' or one of its dependencies.
>   The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another
>   process. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070020) ".

Now, I've found a few posts like this and the answer is mostly that some other application is running on port 80, 8080 etc blocking visual studio's iis express. The problem is that I get this error **regardless** of port I'm using (even on some random 34535 etc).

The interesting part is that when I run kestrel (app on asp.net 5) it works and runs fine without any error.

Anyone has any ideas ?

Comment: You're not alone - I'm seeing exactly the same thing in VS2015 community (and I also relatively recently upgraded to Windows 10). The assembly it chokes on is random, and very occasionally it loads all of the assemblies and works correctly. Unfortunately the more assemblies in use, the less likely the thing is to run...

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I had this issue and resolved it by uninstalling Panda antivirus, which presumably was locking the assemblies for just long enough to interfere with loading them *some of the time*.

If anyone else is having this issue, and there is definitely an assembly that won't load (as opposed to a port that's already been bound to) then try checking your antivirus!